# How to get Buildconf & Configure scripts for PHP5

Tags: php

Am trying to install a package which has given instructions to use Buildconf from the root of php build directory. In my php build directory's root(/etc/php5), I don't find a Buildconf or Configure script. How do I get these? I installed my php5 using sudo apt-get(yes, I have an Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably have installed is PHP binary package, i.e. already built one. If you need to build a stand-alone PHP module, you may want to install package `php5-dev` and use utility `/usr/bin/phpize5` to generate config files.

If what you really need is PHP source, you may download it from http://www.php.net/downloads.php. After you unpack the package, `buildconf` will be there.

If neither of these is what you need, I guess it would be helpful to post the instructions you received.

Comment: Thanks, I got it from the source.